# How to use clojure.string/join in clojurescript

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

I have the following function:

```
(defn join [a] (clojure.string/join  " " a))
```

But I always got an error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: clojure is not defined
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to include the module in the namespace form:

```
(ns my-app.core
  (:require [clojure.string :as string]))

(clojure.string/blank? "")

(string/blank? "")
```

https://github.com/swannodette/lt-cljs-tutorial/blob/master/lt-cljs-tutorial.cljs#L22-L33

If you have trouble, try cleaning and restarting the compiler (`lein do cljsbuild clean, cljsbuild auto`)